# I would like to wire a fuel pump kill switch in my 1995 Ford Ranger XLT

Tags: ford, fuel-system, ranger, pump

Currently, despite a new ignition switch. (including tunnel) My Ranger will not turn off. With the truck in park, key in the off position, and even removed, it just keeps on keepin on. As of right now, I've already installed a Swan Battery Switch.  But I have to pull the fuel pump fuse, in order to stop the motor. Im having a heck of a time locating the pumps hot wire. At least where it enters the cab. So I pushed the positive wire from a toggle into the fuse location and grounded it to the frame. It seems to work so far. But Im concerned Im gonna mess up the truck further by wiring to a fuse. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I cant afford a new steering column or any physical help from a tech.(New steering colomn was what is prescribed.) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First what you describe as grounding one side of the fuse does not sound good - I would stop doing that.

Find the wire colors that go to the pump and trace them in the cab in the bundle of wires going to the back. Once found just put the on/off switch in series in that wire - a handy anti-theft.

You could consider finding the wire supplying the coil and putting a switch there - this would have the advantage of stopping the drain overnight - if it is the supply to coil keeping the engine running.

If it is carbon build-up keeping the engine running then a clean or rebuild will be necessary.